# jQuery Twitter API returning 403 forbidden on server

Tags: json, jquery, twitter, http-status-code-403

I've been working on a site that implements Twitter's API using jQuery's $.ajax function. It works when I run it on my machine, but when I upload it to my server and run it, it returns at 403: forbidden every time. I definitely haven't exceeded their rate limit, so I don't think I've been blacklisted. A few of my colleagues have developed similar problems in their pages since around midnight last night. Does anyone know if Twitter is changing their API? Have they depreciated the json requests?

Here is my code for those interested:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=not+art&rpp=100&callback=?",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                d = data.results;

                for(i=0;i<d.length;i++){
                    var idStr = d[i].id_str;
                    console.log(i+" = "+idStr);
                }
            }
         });
 });
```

I'm fairly certain it's not a code issue since it still works running offline, but there isn't any word from twitter on recent changes that I can find. Any help or info would be greatly appreciated. Are we all going to have to learn a new API?

*EDIT 3/29/13*
The problem appears to be connected to using a shared IP address to access the search.twitter.com API. The Twitter Developer forums didn't have any more information than that, unfortunately, but if you are having similar problems, look into that.